# If statement not working for Safari on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari

Here is the code, which is working fine on desktop browsers, but for some reason is breaking when I use it on Safari on my iPad.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf("playground") != -1)
{
    toggleDisplay(0);
    alert("pgroud");
}
```

The `url.indexOf("playground")` is returning `21`, I checked on iPad, so the code should be working, but the function and the alert are not being called.

Comment: Replace `window.location.href` with just `window.location`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus When you convert `window.location` to a string, it's the same as `window.location.href`.

Comment: If `url` contains `"21"`, then `url.indexOf("playground") == -1`, so it shouldn't run the code.

Comment: Did you mean to say that `indexOf()` returns 21?

Comment: It's very unlikely that `if` doesn't work, that would break nearly every Javascript site. My guess is you're getting an error when it tries to call `toggleDisplay()`. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I did mean to say that indexOf is returning 21, not the variable itself. I am not able to check the console since it is on an iPad.

Comment: [How to enable Safari console in iOS](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/07/enable-safari-debug-console-ios/)